# How to recognize malicious source code?

Tags: delphi, open-source, virus

**BE AWARE! Creating spyware, computer viruses and similar nasties can be illegal where you live and is considered extremely unethical by almost everyone.** Still, I need to ask this to raise awareness about how easy it is to create one. I am asking this after the W32/Induc-A was introduced to this world by someone who came up with a nasty way to spread one. So I want to know how a virus can be created so I will be able to recognise them in the future!

**Recently a [new virus](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/39851) was discovered which spreads itself by replacing the developers' copies of library code.** Actually, through the source code of Delphi 4 through 7. What happened is that there's a virus in the wild which searches the computer for a file called SYSCONST.PAS, to which it will add itself as source code. This file happens to be a source file for the runtime libraries of Delphi. (This runtime source code is available for Delphi developers.) As a result, after being infected a programmer would create lots of new versions of this virus without even knowing it. Since virus scanners sometimes generate false positives many developers might thus decide to ignore the warnings of the scanner and maybe they'll even disable their scanner while building their project. To make it worse, their project might even trigger the scanners of their customers so it's likely that those programmers won't check their source code but will just try to fool the scanner somehow. That is, if a virus scanner is even able to recognise the virus, which isn't very likely. **Thus, we software developers might be creating viruses without realizing what we're doing!**

So, how to create a virus? Simple: get your source code infected by a virus and you're done!

Okay, so the source code of Delphi 4 through 7 might be infected. All Delphi developers, please check your source files! The case is just a proof-of-concept and apparently it can be very successful. Besides, most virus scanners won't check source code but just focus on executables. This virus could stay undetected for quite a while.

**This virus also was successful because it misused source code.** Delphi is a commercial project and the source code is available. But who is sure that these hackers won't be attacking open-source projects in similar ways? There are lots of open-source projects out there and who is going to check them all making sure they're all behaving in a decent way? And if someone is checking the code, will he be able to recognise if something is malicious code?

**So, to make sure we can recognize malicious source code, I have to ask:** How do I create a virus? How do I recognise the code that will create a virus? What is it that most malware will want to do?

---

There is a bit of discussion about the Delphi runtime source code, about this code being open-source or not. Borland uses a dual-license for their source code from the moment when they started to support Linux with Kylix. As a result, the source code has a "GPL" symbol declared which indicates if the libraries are compiled as GPL code or not. As GPL, the source code would be open-source. This also happens to be the source version that was attacked by the virus. Anyway, to avoid discussions here, I've asked [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388114/is-the-delphi-runtime-code-open-source-or-not) so we can focus more on the virus problem and less on Delphi. Basically, we're talking about a virus that attacks source code. Technically, all source code could be at risk but open source code is a likely candidate since hackers know it's structure and can target those files that are rarely modified, thus rarely checked. (And if they can hack their way into a CVS system, they could even erase the traces of their modifications, thus no one might notice the modiifications!)

Comment: Because the information can be misused by not-so-smart people to actually create one! The ILOVEYOU virus wasn't created by a smart, malicious hacker but by some dumb teenager who created it and released it by accident. I happen to be old enough to remember the Christmas Tree EXEC virus, which wreaked havok in 1987 but which too was just created as a prank. It's like letting your 4-year old playing with a loaded gun, unsupervised. Often, nothing bad will happen but it's not ethical...

Comment: Sorry for the pedantry, but do you think you could use a term other than "open source?" Perhaps something like "exposed source" would get your point across without potentially confusing people.

Comment: The term "open source" is better, since it's open-source that is most likely to be attacked this way. The Delphi source code wasn't exposed, it's open for all Delphi developers. (And C#Builder developers.) More open-source projects could be at risk, especially if some malicious changes have been made to sourcefiles that are rarely modified or checked, but which still are parts of popular projects.

Comment: I don't agree that open-source is more susceptible. Open source is likely to be viewed by many more developers than closed-source code, and open-source projects tend to have version control, diffs, etc. Closed-source might be viewed by only one person.  Thus, **closed source may be more susceptible to a source code exploit**.  In any case, I would not emphasize open source so much.

Comment: Is open-source really checked that much by developers? Are there really developers who will check each and every file of a project made of over 500 source files? Will a file called sysconst.cpp, sysconst.cs, sysconst.pas or sysconst.php really be checked for malicious code, that might appear within the 5000 constants in the file? Sure! At one time, someone will discover it. Could take days, week, months, even longer. Then again, even regular malware gets discovered in time, often too late.

Comment: @Alex: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but you seem to be not very knowledgeable about the way Open Source software works. It seems to me you are setting up a lot of straw-men here. How would any modification that introduces really dangerous payload (altering or deleting files, executing code received over a network connection, relaying mails or other IP traffic) not be obvious to even casual inspection of the code? Introducing buffer overflows would be much less suspicious, and there are surely already enough existing in unmanaged code that could be (ab)used.

Comment: @mghie, don't doubt my experience. I see a risk where someone injected malicious code to a source file. As someone already said, Ken Thompson already wondered if it was possible to introduce a virus to code by infecting it at the source. (Or rather, by infecting .OBJ files.) This was in the Orson-year 1984. I go a step further and wonder if it will be noticed soon enough when someone adds malicious code to open-source code. Considering the amount of projects at sourceforge.net, I don't think it's even possible to check all open-source files for malicious code. Sooner or later, it will happen.

Comment: @Alex: I still don't see the problem. People having commit rights to SF.net projects are probably not the ones to commit malicious code. If you are afraid of that you should **never** execute any third-party code that you haven't examined the source code of and haven't built yourself. It's exactly the question of trust that the modified compiler raises, and for that matter: Why would you trust the Delphi compiler, then? Because it's not Open Source and you have paid for it? How would a well-run OS repository pose risks that a commercial vendor wouldn't have?

Comment: @mghie, the focus of my Q is on hackers who are infecting executables through the source code. This Delphi example seems to me to be just a proof-of-concept and it seems to be successful. The next attack might be more random in infecting code, but I do expect a next attack. I already was careful with third-party executables. Now I'm also very careful with third-party source code!

Comment: It's not a matter of open-source vs. closed source. The risk is just source code in general that could be infected. With open-source, such a virus would spread more easily, as others might blindly copy the source from some code repository without checking the contents.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While this does not really answer your question, I think a really interesting paper to read is [Reflections on Trusting Trust](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=2&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ece.cmu.edu%2F~ganger%2F712.fall02%2Fpapers%2Fp761-thompson.pdf&ei=MQKkSvXfHdOc8Qa65JnyDw&usg=AFQjCNHEfcr3nqaWB49hKiQMr8soeNbbkA&sig2=RSV3Avxxn6ymDFGYGLbzZA) by Ken Thompson.  It raises a fascinating point that *even if your source code is free of defects (viruses, trojans, etc.), you might still be producing defective executables if your compiler is defective*.  And even if you rebuild the compiler from clean source code, you can still have the same problem.

Unless you're building your computer from the ground up with your own microchips, hand-assembling your own BIOS, writing your own operating system, compiler, and software, you have to draw the line somewhere and *trust* that the hardware and software upon which you're building your systems are correct.

Comment: Well, trust is what counts. But as it is, some hacker decided to infect an open-source project at the source! This will be copied by many other hackers who will attempt to infect more open-source code, where possible. So, first of all I want to create awareness. And also, I want useful tips on how to recognise these malicious code snippets.

Comment: Strangely enough this is now very relevant with the current Snowden/NSA revelations.

Comment: David A. Wheeler presented a way to counter the "trusting trust" attack with a method called [Diverse Double Compiling](http://www.dwheeler.com/trusting-trust/) in his dissertation.

Answer (score 5):

You could check for the Evil Bit on incoming packets... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_bit

Answer (score 4):

If you want to recognize malware, you must know how it works. This means researching malware and aquirering the skill to produce malware.

- search for 29A - they wrote papers on virus
- read about rootkits (there are even books on it)
- read about reverse engineering
- read source code of malware - there's plenty of it in the web.
- learn assembler
- learn about your OS
- reverse the os-kernel
- get clam-av, check the source

I won't provide links here. They are easily found though.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to learn, and are willing to put in the time, your time is probably better spent on google to find then participate in a greyhat community.  this topic is highly complex.

if your question is as simple as "what's an easy way to recognize a virus from its source code", well, it probably won't be easy, because there's infinite ways to go about it.

Comment: But what about recognising their behaviour in some generic way? For example, recognisable patterns in the code? At least, recognisable for us, humans.

Comment: It follows, though, that virus design would change to avoid detection.

Comment: I recently read a book about the "Myths of Security". Basically, it said that viruses are becoming hard to detect not because they're new, but because they're able to modify themselves by e.g. using encryption and packing techniques. A virus that infects open-source code would also be difficult to detect simply because it becomes part of many other applications. The biggest problem it has, though, it that it has a signature that can be recognised, though.

Comment: I've seen it be as simple as "=" instead of "==" in a C program.  It can be impossible to tell the difference between a typo and a deliberate security hole.  In the end, that's what you really want, anyway: to all identify security issues, not just deliberate security issues.

Answer (score 2):

You ask "What is it that most malware will want to do?".

An excellent source for this sort of information is [The Hacker Quarterly](http://www.2600.com/), which is so mainstream, you may find it at your local bookstore, or [you can subscribe online to get it mailed to you](http://store.2600.com/subscriptions.html).

It was started to help hackers and phreakers share information. It is still very popular with hackers today and is considered by many to be controversial in nature.

[image: Cover of The Hacker Quarterly, Summer 2009 issue]

Contents of the Current Issue include:

- Not The Enemy
- Regaining Privacy in a Digital World
- The Security-Conscious Uncle
- Why the "No-Fly List" is a Fraud
- TELECOM INFORMER
- Finding Information in the Library of Congress
- Hacking the DI-524 Interface
- Simple How-to on Wireless and Windows Cracking
- If You Can't Stand the Heat, Hack the Computers!
- Security: Truth Versus Fiction
- Hacking the Beamz
- HACKER PERSPECTIVE: Jason Scott
- iTunes Stored Credit Card Vulnerability
- Zipcar's Information Infrastructure
- The How and Why of Hacking the U.N.
- Listen to Radio Hackers!
- HACKER SPACES - EUROPE
- Abusing Metadata
- Verizon FIOS Wireless Insecurities
- TRANSMISSIONS
- Using Network Recon to Solve a Problem
- Suing Telemarketers for Fun and Profit
- HACKER HAPPENINGS
- Plus LETTERS and MARKETPLACE

There is also [an excellent series of articles on Hacking at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker_(computing)) and [on Computer Viruses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_virus).

... And yes, it is important for programmers to understand how hacking and code breaking works, so they can do the best they can to circumvent it in their programs.

Comment: We also need to understand it so we can recognize it in other people's work! With closed source, there's the risk from co-workers adding malicious code but those risks are reasonably wel limited and easier to trace than hacks in source code that's available for many people, like open source and the runtime source of Delphi. (And to be honest, Delphi is real popular amongst hackers.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between malicious code and an unintentional security bug.

You might as well be asking "How can I write a useful program that has no bugs and is impossible to exploit".

As we all learn in CS its impossible to even write debuggers to catch infinite loops let alone intelligent malevolence.

My advice for security conscious applications is an ex(p|t)ensive code review and use of commercially available static analysis software.

Comment: Yes, there is! Security bugs are hidden for everyone. Malicious code is known by at leaso one person after it's added, thus the abuse of this code will start sooner. While security bugs are bad, malicious code is worse since they're going to be misused from the moment of creation. Besides, malicious code can occur in any source file. Thus, they can even be exploited by applications that have nothing to do with security.

Comment: If my intent wasn't clear I'm sorry.  My response was intended to be couched in the context of discovery of malicious code and was not intended to address exploitation.